# Gnuplot with Linear Regression

Tags: gnuplot, multiple-columns, regression

I am trying to apply linear regression with (Fit(x)). Instead of having two columns in a data file, e.g. x and y values, this file have, for example, 5 columns. I want to pick the avg value of each column and feed it to the F(X) function.

Data:

```
A   B   C   D   E
2   2   5   10  20
4   5   6   11  1
6   8   7   12  4
8   9   12  13  8
10  11  10  14  17
```

Could I?

Thanks for help

Comment: What have you tried yourself? We will help you figure out where your code fails, but we will not create complete solutions.

Comment: This isn't completely clear.  Could you supply some sample data and sample output showing what you want to do?

Comment: for example, if we have a file with following values:

Comment: Please edit this question instead of posting a new identical question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737080/gnuplot-with-linear-regression2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737080/gnuplot-with-linear-regression2)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your data is as specified and you wish to fit a function `f(x)=m*x+b` to the data where the 0-based column index (0,1,2,3 or 4) should be the x value and the column average should be the y value.  We need to construct a new data file that contains the averages.

In gnuplot 5, we can use something called *inline data*.  This is a special variable that behaves like a file.  We will find the average of each column of the data and construct an inline data variable containing these.  We do this by looping over the column indices and applying the stats function.  The print command can be instructed to print to an inline data variable.

```
set print $l append
do for [i=1:5] {
    stats datafile u i nooutput
    print STATS_mean
}
set print  # restores ordinary print behavior
```

With your data, we can see what is contained in $l by printing it with `print $l`:

```
6.0
7.0
8.0
12.0
10.0
```

We now can apply the fit command with this data

```
f(x) = m*x + b
fit f(x) $l u 0:1 via m,b
```

This will fit the data so that f(x) = average of column x (or as close to it as can be obtained with the fit).

[image]

---

In gnuplot 4.6, inline data is not available, but we can use a temporary file.  Replacing all occurrences of `$l` with `"tempfile"` will work the same (except for the `print $l` command), but will add the data to a temporary file named **tempfile**.